# bash returning from recursion

Tags: bash, recursion, subdirectory

I have to search all subdirs recursively and print *(number of * = depth of file/dir) type and name. The problem comes when i enter dir and then want to get out but nothing happens.

my test file

```
DIR test
*FILE ace
*FILE base
*DIR father
**FILE cookies
*DIR mother
**DIR how
***FILE youdoing
*FILE zebra
```

my code

maxDepth is how far in to the dir it can go(default 3) and currDepth is 1 at the beginning

```
    function tree(){
        maxDepth=$2
        currDepth=$3
        #print the starting file
        if [ "$currDepth" -eq 0 ];then
            printf  "%s   %s\n" DIR "$1"
            currDepth=1
        fi
        for path in "$1"/*;do
            for i in $( seq 1 $currDepth );do       
                echo -n *
            done
            if [ -d "$path" ];then
                printf  "%s   %s\n" DIR "${path##*/}"           
                if [[ "$currDepth" -lt "$maxDepth" ]];then
                    tree "$path" "$maxDepth" "$(( currDepth + 1 ))"
                fi
                continue
            fi
            if [ -f "$path" ];then      
                printf "%s  %s\n" FILE "${path##*/}"
                continue
            fi
            if [ -L "$path" ];then
                printf "%s  %s\n" LINK "${path##*/}"
                continue            
            fi
       done
  }
```

my output

```
DIR test
*FILE ace
*FILE base
*DIR father
**FILE cookies
**DIR mother
***DIR how
***FILE zebra
```

what am i doing wrong

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is you should use the find command

Comment: It specifically says i should use recursion

Comment: This function isn't recursive. It doesn't call `tree`, it just calls `printf tree …`.

Comment: Don't know how that printf sneaked in there

Comment: Question:what do you want to do with it? is it just to learn recursion in bash or do you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used local in front of `currDepth=$3`

Answer (score 1):

1. Debug your script by doing `set -x` before you run it.
2. Make sure integers are always integers by declaring them with the `-i` integer attribute.
3. Use expression syntax consistently. It's a good idea to always use `[[ ]]` tests for string comparisons and `(( ))` for arithmetic and numeric comparisons, if your target shell is bash.
4. Use `(( ))` for loops instead of `seq`, which is nonstandard.
5. Explicitly declare your variables in the function (using `local` or `declare`) to ensure they are scoped to the function.
6. Actually call the inner `tree`.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
tree() {
    local -i maxDepth=$2 # Make sure these values are always integers
    local -i currDepth=$3

    # print the starting file
    if (( currDepth == 0 )); then # use bash arithmetic
        printf  "%s   %s\n" DIR "$1"
        currDepth=1
    fi
    for path in "$1"/*;do
        for ((i=0; i<currDepth; i++)); do
            printf '*'
        done
        if [[ -d "$path" ]];then
            printf  "%s   %s\n" DIR "${path##*/}"           
            if [[ "$currDepth" -lt "$maxDepth" ]];then
                tree "$path" "$maxDepth" "$(( currDepth + 1 ))"
            fi
            continue
        fi
        if [[ -f "$path" ]];then      
            printf "%s  %s\n" FILE "${path##*/}"
            continue
        fi
        if [[ -L "$path" ]];then
            printf "%s  %s\n" LINK "${path##*/}"
            continue            
        fi
   done
}
```

Comment: Fixed the syntax but it seems something is wrong with recursion. Like it doesn't even return to the start file, plus currDepth never changes back to 1

Comment: @user2202368 : `1. Debug your script by doing set -x before you run it.`. Did you try that? Good luck.

Comment: I'm doing right now, these continue-s are suspicious

Comment: there's a problem with currDepth, it doesn't change back, any suggestions

Comment: Yes, use the `local` keyword to make sure that your variables are scoped to the function. I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using find, stat and sed:

```
find <DIR> -exec stat --printf="%n,%F\n" "{}" \; | \
 sed -r -e "s/[^\/]+\//\*/g" -e "s/regular file/FILE/" -e "s/directory/DIR/" | \
 sed -r -e "s/([\*]+)([^,]+),(.+)/\1 \3 \2/"
```

**IMPORTANT:** Use DIR not DIR/ otherwise DIR name will not appear in results.

**Explanation:**

`find` returns recursively all files and directory within DIR.

`-exec` option in `find` allows to pass each result to another command.
Here I'm passing each result to the command `stat`

`stat` has an option to format the output `-printf` (see manpage) :

- `%n` is the filename (with relavtive path)
- `%F` is the file type ( regular file, directory,symbolic link,block special file...)

So,

`find <DIR> -exec stat --printf="%n,%F\n" "{}" \;`

returns the following, one result by line (assuming that there are only regular files and directories in DIR) :

```
DIR/path/to/file,regular file
DIR/path/to/dir,directory
```

Then, I'm using sed to transform each line the way you required using regular expression:

1. Replace `string/` by `*` -> `***basename,file type`
2. Replace `"regular file"` by `FILE`
3. Replace `"directory"` by `DIR`
4. Shuffle around `basename` and `filetype` using **back referencing** in sed.

**NOTE:** I will not explain in details how regular expressions work as it would be too long.

Comment: I have no f**king idea what you did here, care to explain

Comment: @user2202368 you basically told us in comments to your question that you didn't want an answer using `find` in lieu of a recursive function. Then you went and accepted an answer using `find` instead of a recursive function. What's up with that?

Comment: Changed the answer, i discovered the meaning of the word local :D